# Salesforce streaming API v 29.0 and Delete Action

Tags: api, ruby

I'm using streaming API v 29.0 + [restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) gem. I created a push topic and subscribed to changes.

If I create a record in Salseforce datebase via Salesforce web interface, I receive message when this record is deleted, if I create a record using REST API I don't receive any messages. But if I update any field of the record before deleting it, I'll receive delete message.

Do you have any ideas why I don't receive messages when delete a record created via API? Is it a sort of a bug?

Answer (score 3):

What you describe does sound odd and perhaps on the face of it a bug, here are few things to consider if you have not done so already...

- I did reviewed the [Message Reliability](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/using_streaming_api_stateless.htm) topic in the docs and it does not say anything about not supporting the creation of events generated via REST API activity, which I'd personally be surprised if it did tbh. It does however state that you may not always get events depending on how often the client reconnects etc. So its worth reviewing what it says from that respect.
- There is also some situations described in the [Security](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/security_pushtopic_query.htm) section that may lead to events not being received that are worth checking as well, if your perhaps using a different user between your UI and API tests this could have an impact on things.
- Finally the way in which the [PushTopic events](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/events.htm) are expressed has changed between v28 and v29, so might be worth reviewing and if felt needed recreate your PushTopic using the new boolean event fields.

As regards raising a case with Salesforce i personally would aim to reproduce via the [Workbench tool support](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/quick_start_workbench.htm) for Streaming API they describe here. This approach may in fact yield new observations in respect to isolating the root of the problem.